# How could I tighten security for this custom Facebook login for Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, facebook

I've written this on a dev environment. I'm providing both a normal login with username and password, as well as a log in with Facebook button on my website

It's working great but I'd like to identify any obvious flaws with my implementation. It goes as follows:

## 1. Initiate login

jQuery picks up the click, calls the Facebook SDK.. If the user authenticated successfully, I send their Facebook ID, email and name via admin-ajax.php (with a nonce).

```
        $('.login-facebook').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        openModal('#facebook-login');
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                FB.api("/me", {fields: 'id, first_name, last_name, email, picture.type(large), locale'},function(response){
                    if(response){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '//'+window.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                            data: {
                                action : 'ajax_facebook_login',
                                user_id : response.id,
                                user_first_name : response.first_name,
                                user_last_name : response.last_name,
                                user_email : response.email,
                                user_picture : response.picture,
                                nonce : $('#ajax_nonce').data('nonce')
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                closeModal('facebook-login');
                                if(data){
                                    window.location.replace(data);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        },{
            scope: 'public_profile, email',
            return_scopes: true
        });
    });
```

## 2. Check for existing users

I take the users info. I check if a user exists with either the Facebook ID, OR the email address from their Facebook account. If yes, they'll be logged in with no further questions asked.

*My worry here - if someone knew the email or Facebook ID of a registered user, could they somehow pass that through to admin-ajax.php, causing the system to log them in? As far as I know I only have a nonce preventing this happening.*

```
$nonce = esc_attr($_POST['nonce']);
    if(!$nonce || !wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'ajax_nonce')) wp_die();

    $user_fb_id = esc_attr($_POST['user_id']);
    $user_email = filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_first_name = esc_attr($_POST['user_first_name']);
    $user_last_name = esc_attr($_POST['user_last_name']);
    $user_picture = esc_attr($_POST['user_picture']);

    // get users with matching facebook id
    $users = get_users(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'facebook_id',
            'meta_value' => $user_fb_id
        )
    );

    // if user exists by facebook id
    if($users[0]){
        $user = $users[0];
    // if user exists by email
    } else if(!empty($user_email) && get_user_by('email', $user_email) != null){
        $user = get_user_by('email', $user_email);
    // no user
    } else {
        $user = null;
    }

    if($user){
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        // only non admins can log in with facebook
        if(user_can($user_id, 'manage_options')) wp_die();
        // update user
        wp_update_user([
            'ID' => $user_id, // this is the ID of the user you want to update.
            'first_name' => $user_first_name,
            'last_name' => $user_last_name
        ]);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'facebook_id', $user_fb_id);
        // log user in
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    }
```

## 3. Handle non-users

If no user was found with the provided ID or email, create the user and log them in automatically.

*Again my worry is that someone could mess things up if they were able to get around the nonce.*

```
        // no user found, register user
    if(!$user){
        if(!$new_user['email']){
            $username = lcfirst($new_user['first_name'][0]) . lcfirst($new_user['last_name']) . '_' . $new_user['id'][3];
        }
        else {
            $username = $new_user['email'];
        }
        $user_id = wp_create_user($username, wp_generate_password(), $user_email);
        wp_update_user([
            'ID' => $user_id,
            'first_name' => $user_first_name,
            'last_name' => $user_last_name
        ]);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'facebook_id', $user_fb_id);
        if (is_wp_error($user_id)) {
            $errors[] = 'Error '. $user_id->get_error_code() .': '. $user_id->get_error_message();
        } else {
            // update the role of the user we just created
            $user = new WP_User($user_id);
            $user->set_role('customer');
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'facebook_id', $user_fb_id);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_image', $user_picture);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'is_activated', 1);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false');
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_admin', 'false');
            // log user in
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
        }
    }
```

I appreciate any comments and if this is useful to anyone else, feel free to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A nonce is only used to make sure that an attacker can't do a replay attack: Meaning, they can't just listen to everything I just sent to the server, do the exact same thing, and be logged in as well.

Since you provide a nonce that can easily be grabbed by an attacker with `$('#ajax_nonce').data('nonce')` it shouldn't be seen as a protection measure.

So yes, someone could just log in by knowing your email and facebookId.
Looking even closer it is either or:

```
if($users[0]){ 
    // If the facebook ID is found it's all good and we use that account
    $user = $users[0];
// if user exists by email
} else if(!empty($user_email) && get_user_by('email', $user_email) != null){
    // If the email is found it's all good and we use that account
    $user = get_user_by('email', $user_email);
// no user
} else {
    $user = null;
}
```

So knowing someone's facebookId OR email is all it takes.

So there are certainly still some flaws you need to resolve before you put this live :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

So in order to verify the user before logging them in. I need to verify the client-side access token that's generated with the JavaScript SDK.

I'm now passing the access token along with their Facebook ID to my PHP function and before creating the log in session, I'm making this curl request to Facebook:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $user_access_token;
```

If the code is valid, it'll return the users full name and Facebook ID that that code is valid for.

I compare the original ID send via AJAX to this ID and if they match, this should authenticate the user.